# Random wierd flashing colors in viewport shading

Tags: 3d-view

Pretty sure its a pc related problem since when i change pc in the office i get the same result. Any file open and then view in viewport shading will get me a bunch of random colors kind of like a rave party if you start moving around the model. What causes this issue and how can i fix this? When i load any of the same files on my home computer they look perfectly normal. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp9k4.png) this also only happens in Eevee, cycles works just fine.
file: https://pasteall.org/blend/bc5dd469d7514b988438922746c58146
[image: ????????]

Comment: Could you share your .blend? (pasteall or blendexchange will do)

Comment: @BlenderMaster15 how can i insert the file into the post? nevermind i misunderstood here: https://pasteall.org/blend/bc5dd469d7514b988438922746c58146

Comment: It looks fine to me in cycles and eevee. https://ibb.co/nwXG6kh
https://ibb.co/5htFbMz       It must be a hardware issue on your end.

Comment: @BlenderMaster15do then its a computer issue, i assume the gpu or cpu cant handle whatever its trying to render

Comment: Perhaps. Are you using Blender 3.1?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @BlenderMaster15 im using the latest version that is on steam whatever that is idk how to check